# How to Search for Items in Firebase Realtime Database from Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I created a Search Bar and want to search for `listItem` (note: I use Firebase Realtime Database)  but there's no good tutorials on how to search in the way that is going to work with mine...if that makes sense.

HomPage:
[image]

Desired Effect:
[image]

Declarations:

```
Query dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');
```

This is the `listItem`:

```
 Widget listItem({
    required Map People,
  }) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      height: 110,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        color: _getBGClr(People['Color']),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(People['Name'], style: textStyle),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Text(People['Place'], style: textStyle),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Text(People['Date'], style: textStyle),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

This is the `FirebaseAnimatedList`:

```
Expanded(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
            query: dbRef,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                Animation<double> animation, int index) {
              Map People = snapshot.value as Map;

              return listItem(People: People);
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Did you see the Firebase documentation on [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)?

Comment: The documents just show how to filter and order it (descending order or alphabetical). I don't think you can use it for search function :( @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

[This video was the answer to my question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyhYmh_SlrA). It shows exactly how to do the thing I want to do.

Video Summary:

```
final searchFilter = TextEditingController();
```

```
TextFormField(
              controller: searchFilter,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              onChanged: (String value) {
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
```

```
Expanded(
            child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
              query: dbRef,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                final title = snapshot.child('Name').value.toString();
                //if
                if (searchFilter.text.isEmpty) {
                  Map People = snapshot.value as Map;
                  return listItem(People: People);
                }
                //else if
                else if (title
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(searchFilter.text.toLowerCase().toString())) {
                  Map People = snapshot.value as Map;
                  return listItem(People: Poeple);
                }
                //else
                else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```